# Por qué me está arrojando el json descifrado con barras invertidas usando openssl y tampoco incluye las llaves '{}'

Tags: php, openssl

Estoy intentando acceder a los json descifrados pero sucede que cuyos json vienen con barras incluidas y sin las llaves '{}' esto usando json_encode() pero si uso json_decode() da como resultado '<empty_string>'.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```js
// RECORRO LOS 3 RESULTADOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS PARA OBTENER 3 CIFRADOS
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($travels_total_user)) {
                                                
                                                // PROCEDO A DESCIFRAR LOS VALORES USANDO OPENSSL
                                                $cipher_decoded_values = base64_decode($value);
                                                
                                                $inicialization_vector = substr($cipher_decoded_values, 0, $inicialization_vector_length);
                                                
                                                $cipher_string_result = substr($cipher_decoded_values, $inicialization_vector_length);
                                                
                                                $decrypted_values_data = openssl_decrypt($cipher_string_result, 'AES-256-CBC', $private_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $inicialization_vector);
                                                
                                                // COMPRUEBO QUE EL DESCIFRADO DE LOS VALORES FUE ÉXITOSO
                                                if ($decrypted_values_data !== false) {
                                                    
                                                    $eee = json_decode($decrypted_values_data);
                                                    // ESTÁ DANDO ERROR, EL JSON ESTÁ SIENDO ARROJADO CON BARRAS INVERTIDAS Y JSON_DECODE NO FUNCIONA DA COMO RESULTADO <EMPTY_STRING>
                                                    
                                                    echo $eee->travel_by;
                                                    
                                                }
                                                
                                            }
```

Comment: Has probado a ver qué te devuelve decrypted_values_data justo antes de hacer el json_decode? Podrías mostrarnos esos resultados?

Comment: @Jakala devuelve un json con barras invertidas, no cambia en nada si uso json_encode

Comment: En PHP tienes las funciones json_last_error y json_last_error_msg. Añádelas después del json_decode para ver que error te está dando. Muchas veces si usamos un echo, print_r, var_dump... Nos muestra la cadena con \ para poder imprimir en pantalla. Mira con las funciones de Json a ver si obtienes más información del error

Comment: @NuevoUsuario sería bueno que compartieras un ejemplo del texto que le estas pasando a la función `json_decode`. Utiliza la opción [edit] para agregarlo en tu pregunta.